# why is this program not able to change the uniform?

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-3

this is my vertex shader code

```
const GLchar* Vshader_source =
        "#version 130 \n"
        "in vec3 position; \n"
        "uniform float moving = 0.0;\n"
        "void main(){ \n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position.x,position.y - moving,position.z,1.0);\n"
        "}";
```

and this is my program's window loop + the uniform selection functions, and the vertices formatting

```
GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib,3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib );

GLint uniVex = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"moving");

time_t new = time(NULL) + 1;
char error_num = 0;
GLfloat vexnum = 0.1f;
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
                glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                if (!error_num){
                        fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",glGetError());
                        error_num++;
                }
                if (time(NULL) == new){
                        new++;
                        glUniform1f(uniVex,vexnum += 0.1f);
                }
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
                glfwSwapBuffers(window);
                glfwPollEvents();
        }
```

it worked before and i could see the triangle when "uniform float moving =0.0;" was removed and gl_position was just "gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);". but when i adjusted it for the uniform it won't draw anything and glgeterror() returns 1282. which i looked up but no one seems to have an answer for what error 1282 is.

Comment: `1282` is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, it's written in your OpenGL headers. Also I don't see where you `glUseProgram`. And I suggest you specify a fixed attribute location with `glBindAttribLocation` (or even better with `layout(location=0)` if supported) rather than querying it afterwards.

Comment: Error 1282 (0x502) is [Invalid Operation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#Meaning_of_errors). Try without the default `moving`value (which is already 0.0 at link time).

Comment: ybungalobill glUseProgram is in there. i just didn't specify my entire code

Answer (score 0):

From `glUniform` man pages, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` occurs in the following situations:

1. is generated if there is no current program object.
2. is generated if the size of the uniform variable declared in the shader does not match the size indicated by the glUniform command.
3. is generated if one of the integer variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable of type float, vec2, vec3, vec4, or an array of these, or if one of the floating-point variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable of type int, ivec2, ivec3, or ivec4, or an array of these.
4. is generated if location is an invalid uniform location for the current program object and location is not equal to -1.
5. is generated if count is greater than 1 and the indicated uniform variable is not an array variable.
6. is generated if a sampler is loaded using a command other than glUniform1i and glUniform1iv.
7. is generated if glUniform is executed between the execution of glBegin() and the corresponding execution of glEnd().

From the excerpt of your code, seems to me that problem could be on item 1 or item 4

Comment: yes i do create a shader program, i just didn't specify it in the code. and i don't know what 4 means.

Comment: Item 4 means that you are passing a value, that is different from -1, to uniform location that does not correspond to which the shader is expecting. But you must be sure that this error is being generated for `glUniform1f`. Others functions, like `glGetUniformLocation` could generate GL_INVALID_OPERATION too